# How to select a list of elements by name?

Tags: javascript

i want to select all the elements that start with a particular sequence.
The sequence will be like work_XXXXXX. how to achieve this?

Comment: What starts with `work_`? The elememt's ID?  The text in the element?

Comment: "select" how? what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing answers in both jquery and javascript but best option is use jquery because with javascript you will have to loop throught all elements and match your desired patteren which is very time consuming process so my preference is use jquery:

finds all inputs with an attribute name that starts with 'work_' and puts text in them.

```html
<input name="newsletter" />

<input name="work_man" />
<input name="work_boy" />
<script>
    $('input[name^="work_"]').val('work here!');
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

with javascript their is no builtin keyword for this, but you can do it by loop through all elements and check for match of your desired pattern, this way:

```js
var idStart = "work_";
var componentContainer = document.getElementById("containerTable").getElementsByTagName("DIV");
for (var i = 0; i < componentContainer.length; i++) {
     var id = componentContainer[i].id;
     if ((id.length >= idStart.length) && (id.substring(0, idStart.length - 1) == idStart))// you can also use regular expression here to match desired pattern
     {
          //do something...
     }
}
```

Comment: The question is not tagged `[jquery]`.

Comment: @alex, he was suggesting that it is easiest to use jQuery than do it manually. The OP might not be aware of how easy jQuery makes things.

Comment: @Nathan MacInnes The first edit didn't suggest that. And it would be easier to do a lot of things - unfortunately, including a JavaScript library is not often possible or necessary.

Comment: @alex: may be user is not aware to use jquery but with this suggested example and links he can call javascript function on match of condition and provide his desired functionality in javascript there

Comment: @Rajesh Rolen- DotNet Developer It would appear from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036556/help-with-this-code) asked that they do know of the existence of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the `id` attribute you can do...

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

var myElems = [];

for(var i = 0, length = elems.length; i < length; i++) {

   if (elems[i].id.match(/^work_/)) {
    myElems.push(elems[i]);
   }

}
```

`myElems` will contain all elements where their `id` attribute starts with `work_`.

[See it on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/F6KDj/)

If you mean the `class` attribute it is a little different.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

var myElems = [];

for(var i = 0, length = elems.length; i < length; i++) {

   var classes = elems[i].className.split(' '); 

   for (var j = 0, classesLength = classes.length; j < classesLength; j++) {    
       // If you have a trim function, use it on the class name.
       if (classes[j].match(/^work_/)) {
           myElems.push(elems[i]);
           break;
       }
   }

}
```

[See it on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/F6KDj/2/)

Of course if you use a library such as jQuery it is much easier.

```
$('*[id^=work')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same class for all such elements and select them by class.